# Combination and permutation : form password with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I'm confused with a combinatory question, I don't know whether i need to use combination or permuatation to solve the question, could anyone help?
Question : How many ways can I use to form a 6-length password with exactly 2 different uppercase and 4 different lowercase?

Thanks in advance if anyone could help.

Comment: Since the order of the letters is important, you should count permutations.

Comment: So the solution should be like this: 26P2 x 26P4?

Comment: $\binom{26}{2}\cdot\binom{26}{4}\cdot(2+4)!$

Comment: Isn't we have to use permutation to solve the question since order is important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me edit my answer since I did not see that the uppercase letters could not contain duplicates and lowercase letters could not contain duplicates.

There are $\binom{26}{2}$ choices for the uppercase letters.

There are $\binom{26}{4}$ choices for the lowercase letters.

There are $6!$ ways to arrange the $6$ letters.

Therefore, there are 
$$
6!\,\binom{26}{2}\binom{26}{4}=3,\!498,\!300,\!000
$$
passwords.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but I don't quite understand your solution, could you explain further?

Comment: Perhaps I've got something wrong here, but IMO the answer is $\binom{26}{2}\cdot\binom{26}{4}\cdot(2+4)!=3498300000$. Keep in mind that the uppercase letters should be different from each other and the lowercase letters should be different from each other (i.e., both are chosen without replacement from the corresponding set).

Comment: @barakmanos: indeed. I missed that we could not have duplicates in the upper or the lower case letters.

Comment: As humans that might seem like a lot of possible passwords. But for a computer that is not even $2^{32}$. Somewhat depressing. :(

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila - don't worry Snowden is your system administrator.